# Download only changed files git

Tags: git, github

I have forked a project on GitHub and I want to download only the changed files from the original repo. Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes and no. You have to get the whole repo, but when you merge it locally, it only brings in the changed files. There is a [walkthrough here](http://help.github.com/forking/).

The important line is this:

```
git remote add upstream git://github.com/original/repo.git
```

And then the actual fetching/merging can be done like this (two steps):

```
git fetch upstream master
git merge upstream/master
```

or in one step:

```
git pull upstream master
```

(Examples take from the GitHub link provided above)

Comment: Just a little rant: git is the worst system ever created by human hands. Poorly conceived, poorly implemented. Said that, thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

`git fetch` (or `git pull` to automatically merge)