# Can you download explicitly Git changes?

Tags: git, github

I've been doing a bit of research, and discovered that you cannot download only the *changed* files. You can only download the whole commit. I think it's referred to as hash? Correct me please, if I am wrong. I would like to get a hold of the changed files between each commit only, is there a way to do it?

The reason this link doesn't work for me: [Download only changed files git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2245593/download-only-changed-files-git) -- is because it's talking about merges. I need the changed files to analyse them, not to merge with my rep.

Comment: You can compare them online, github shows the diff

Comment: Yh, but can I download that? I need to analyse the changed files. I am actually writing a script to analyse many changes at once, so I need something computable, not viewable.

Comment: How does the analysis look like ?

Comment: I use PMD to find new 'bugs', in the nutshell

Comment: as @Marged mentioned, "diff" should work to list the files that have changed between two commits. Then you can download those files using "archive" to download the file from the repo at a specific commit

Comment: The command would be: `git diff <commit1> <commit2>` (within the same rep)??

Comment: Found the issue, nvm! Haven't updated my rep properly! Many thx!

Answer (score 1):

Git holds only[1] the full version of files. When you use `git diff` (or any other command that shows a diff) the file differences are generated on the fly (this is how so many different formats are supported).

A commit that, for example, changes a single file is a link to a listing of the files that make up the working tree, one of these will will be a new version of the file, the rest the same as the previous commit.

See https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-Internals for far more details.

[1] There are some optimisations with pack files, but that is mostly an implementation detail.

Comment: The file differences. What about the difference of all files between two commits? Like, one commit is different from the next because the next has two files changed. `git diff` seems to work only with individual files.

Comment: Forgive me if I'm wrong, I am trying to figure it out.

What would be the command to use to compare two commits from the same branch?

Comment: I get "fatal: bad object" when I try to `git diff <commit1> <commit2>`

Comment: Found the issue, nvm! Haven't updated my rep properly! Many thx!